# passing an ASP variable to a javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

Is it possible to pass an ASP.net GridView row value to a javascript?

```
$('#<%=gvOrder.ClientID %> .reqButton').live('click', function(){
     var next = $("#summaryTable").closest('tr');

     next.after('<tr><td>-gv row variable here-</td><td>-gv row variable-</td></tr>');
 });
```

The situation is I have a GridView that looks like this:

```
Product  -  Quantity Available -  Qty to Order -   Button
Nail     -  2                  -    (txtBox)   -  (reqButton)    
xx       -  3                  -    (txtBox)   -  (reqButton)
```

And I have an HTML table beside it which servers as a Summary table so that everytime the user clicks (reqButton), it adds a row with the data depending on which row the reqButton was clicked.

So when the user puts a 1 on (txtBox) and clicked the reqButton on the row Nail, it should a row:

```
(summaryTable)
Nail   -    1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think passing a value to javascript is the same as passing a value to html.
(Asp.net engine will evaluate these placehoder variables before passing them to the client browser)

for your reference:

```
$('#<%=gvOrder.ClientID %> .reqButton').live('click', function(){
     var next = $("#summaryTable").closest('tr');
     var rowVariable = $("<%=gvOrder.ClientID %> .quality").value() //this is a row variable
     next.after("<tr><td>" + rowVariable + "</td><td>-gv row variable-</td></tr>");
 });
```

Comment: How can I set the rowVariable to "Nail" for example? Because I only know how to get that value in C#, like gv.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text